# swipe tests flaky on RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have one RecyclerView with ItemTouchHelper to swipe the internal items LEFT and RIGHT - when I perform swipeLeft() and swipeRight() on them via espresso like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.pass_recyclerview)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition(0,swipeRight()));
```

but unfortunately the tests are flaky - on some devices they work and on some they don't - is there a reliable way to perform this swipe action? I already played around with other EDGE_FUZZ_FACTORs - but this is also not the way to make it work 100%

Update:
I debugged the problem a bit more - somehow on some devices there is a cancel event in between:

event_t1 = {android.view.MotionEvent@830019549128} "MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=546.0, y[0]=40.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=788701990, downTime=788701990, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }"

event_t2 = {android.view.MotionEvent@830019178264} "MotionEvent { action=ACTION_CANCEL, id[0]=0, x[0]=500.98276, y[0]=40.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=1, eventTime=788722868, downTime=788701990, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }"

I see this on the "public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView recyclerView, MotionEvent event)" of ItemTouchHelper.
These are the only events I see there - Interestingly when activating the Screen overlay showing touch data then I see the swipe completing fine after this cancel on ~1/10 the way

Comment: add please logcat of failed tries. Maybe this recyclerView is not correctly seen on some devices

Comment: No I see the recyclerviews for sure

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that default swipeLeft/Right implementation is using press type FINGER (this means 16x16 mm). You can try to create your own swipe implementation as [described here](http://qathread.blogspot.ru/2014/01/discovering-espresso-for-android-swiping.html).

Comment: I tried all Press.FINGER, Press.PINPOINT, Press.Thumb - same behaviour - also with different EDGE_FUZZ_FACTORs - no way to fix this for all devices this way